# How to save Qlistwidget items in database or in txt file

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt, pyqt5

Hello recently I made app which will I show you below. In pyqt5 I want to save qlistwidget items in txt or in database file but I don't know how to do that and also I want to show automatically saved qlistwidget items in qlistwidget when I will run my app. Also I want to delete selected item from qlistwidget in database and also in qlistwidget Please help me how to do that I have no idea where to start from

I have no idea how to do that

```
# I am using Pyqt5
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QInputDialog, QLineEdit


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.MW = MainWindow
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(288, 267)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(270, 114))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(630, 540))
        MainWindow.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(285, 260))
        MainWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("QMainWindow{background-color:#6F2232;}")
        MainWindow.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonIconOnly)
        MainWindow.setDocumentMode(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("QWidget{background-color:#6F2232;}")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(9, 9, -1, -1)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, -1, -1, -1)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        self.listWidget.setFont(font)
        self.listWidget.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.listWidget.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.listWidget.setStyleSheet("QListWidget{Background-color:#282828;\n"
                                      "color:#FFFFFF}")
        self.listWidget.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.listWidget.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.listWidget.setLineWidth(1)
        self.listWidget.setModelColumn(0)
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 288, 21))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.menubar.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.menubar.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.menubar.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.menubar.setStyleSheet("QMenuBar{background-color:#C3083F;\n"
                                   "color:#FFFFFF}")
        self.menubar.setDefaultUp(False)
        self.menubar.setNativeMenuBar(True)
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuFile = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(9)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.menuFile.setFont(font)
        self.menuFile.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.menuFile.setStyleSheet("background-color:#C3083F;\n"
                                    "color:#FFFFFF;")
        self.menuFile.setToolTipsVisible(True)
        self.menuFile.setObjectName("menuFile")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.toolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar.setEnabled(True)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.toolBar.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.toolBar.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.toolBar.setFocusPolicy(QtCore.Qt.StrongFocus)
        self.toolBar.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.toolBar.setStyleSheet("QToolBar{background-color:#282828;\n"
                                   "border:#282828;\n"
                                   "padding:2px;}\n")
        self.toolBar.setMovable(True)
        self.toolBar.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.AllToolBarAreas)
        self.toolBar.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.toolBar.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(25, 39))
        self.toolBar.setFloatable(True)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName("toolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.LeftToolBarArea, self.toolBar)
        self.actionAdd = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\WORK\test\task\plus.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionAdd.setIcon(icon)
        self.actionAdd.setShortcutContext(QtCore.Qt.WindowShortcut)
        self.actionAdd.setAutoRepeat(True)
        self.actionAdd.setVisible(True)
        self.actionAdd.setMenuRole(QtWidgets.QAction.TextHeuristicRole)
        self.actionAdd.setIconVisibleInMenu(True)
        self.actionAdd.setShortcutVisibleInContextMenu(False)
        self.actionAdd.setObjectName("actionAdd")
        self.actionRemove = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon1 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon1.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\WORK\test\task\minus.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionRemove.setIcon(icon1)
        self.actionRemove.setAutoRepeat(True)
        self.actionRemove.setVisible(True)
        self.actionRemove.setIconVisibleInMenu(True)
        self.actionRemove.setShortcutVisibleInContextMenu(False)
        self.actionRemove.setObjectName("actionRemove")
        self.actionUp = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon2 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon2.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\WORK\test\task\up-arrow (1).png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionUp.setIcon(icon2)
        self.actionUp.setAutoRepeat(True)
        self.actionUp.setVisible(True)
        self.actionUp.setIconVisibleInMenu(True)
        self.actionUp.setShortcutVisibleInContextMenu(False)
        self.actionUp.setObjectName("actionUp")
        self.actionDown = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon3 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon3.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\WORK\test\task\download.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionDown.setIcon(icon3)
        self.actionDown.setAutoRepeat(True)
        self.actionDown.setVisible(True)
        self.actionDown.setIconVisibleInMenu(True)
        self.actionDown.setShortcutVisibleInContextMenu(False)
        self.actionDown.setObjectName("actionDown")
        self.actionSort = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon4 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon4.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\WORK\test\task\sort (1).png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionSort.setIcon(icon4)
        self.actionSort.setAutoRepeat(True)
        self.actionSort.setVisible(True)
        self.actionSort.setIconVisibleInMenu(True)
        self.actionSort.setShortcutVisibleInContextMenu(False)
        self.actionSort.setObjectName("actionSort")
        self.actionNotepad = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        icon5 = QtGui.QIcon()
        icon5.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(":/task/spiral_bound_booklet_64px.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Normal, QtGui.QIcon.Off)
        self.actionNotepad.setIcon(icon5)
        self.actionNotepad.setObjectName("actionNotepad")
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionAdd)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionRemove)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionUp)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionDown)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionSort)
        self.menuFile.addAction(self.actionNotepad)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuFile.menuAction())
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionAdd)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionRemove)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionUp)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionDown)
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionSort)
        self.actionAdd.triggered.connect(self.actAdd)
        self.actionRemove.triggered.connect(self.actRemove)
        self.actionUp.triggered.connect(self.actUp)
        self.actionDown.triggered.connect(self.actDown)
        self.actionSort.triggered.connect(self.actSort)
        #self.actionRemove.triggered.connect(self.actEdit)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.menuFile.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "File"))
        self.toolBar.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "toolBar"))
        self.actionAdd.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add"))
        self.actionRemove.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Remove"))
        self.actionUp.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Up"))
        self.actionDown.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Down"))
        self.actionSort.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Sort"))
        self.actionNotepad.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Notepad"))

    #Here when I will trigger this function I want to add item 
    #qlistwidget and also add what I wrote in database or txt file 
    #AUTOMATICALLY. I dont know how to do it please help

    def actAdd(self):
        row = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        QInputDialog.setStyleSheet(self.MW,"QInputDialog{background-color:#C3083F;}")
        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self.MW,"Add","Add Task")
        if ok and text is not None:
            self.listWidget.insertItem(row,text)

    # Here I want to remove qlistwidget item and remove it from database or in 
    # txt file too

    def actRemove(self):
        row = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        item = self.listWidget.item(row)
        if item is None:
            return
        else:
            item = self.listWidget.takeItem(row)
            del item

    def actUp(self):
        row = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        if row >=1:
            item = self.listWidget.takeItem(row)
            self.listWidget.insertItem(row -1, item)
            self.listWidget.setCurrentItem(item)

    def actDown(self):
        row = self.listWidget.currentRow()
        if row < self.listWidget.count() -1:
            item = self.listWidget.takeItem(row)
            self.listWidget.insertItem(row +1, item)
            self.listWidget.setCurrentItem(item)

    def actSort(self):
        self.listWidget.sortItems()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You used the Designer to create that didnt you?  As that looks like the horribly inefficient extremely poorly designed ugly to read code that it churns out.  I suggest you get away from using that tool and learn how to create that code more efficiently and readable so that when you work on it you can do what you need to do more easily.  Note designing the stuff from scratch actually does not take that much more time than it does using the designer and it has the added benefit of helping you understand what you are ultimately doing.

Comment: Here is a solid example of good design -- https://forum.qt.io/topic/104690/how-can-i-connect-qcombobox-with-qlineedit-to-import-data-from-xml-file/20

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4656159/dennis-jensen Dennis Jensen Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing the data to disk every time you add or remove an entry in the list you could instead only write the data when the app exists. This can be achieved by subclassing `QMainWindow` and overriding `closeEvent` like in the example below. In this example the data is saved to `save_file.txt`. To automatically read in the saved data when the window is initiated you could override `MyMainWindow.__init__`, e.g.

```
# Ui_MainWindow() as before

class MyMainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.save_file = 'save_file.txt'
        self.read_from_file(self.save_file)

    def write_to_file(self, file):
        try:
            list_widget = self.ui.listWidget
            entries = '\n'.join(list_widget.item(ii).text() for ii in range(list_widget.count()))
            with open(file, 'w') as fout:
                fout.write(entries)
        except OSError as err:
            print(f"file {file} could not be written")

    def read_from_file(self, file):
        try:
            list_widget = self.ui.listWidget
            with open(file, 'r') as fin:
                entries = [e.strip() for e in fin.readlines()]
            list_widget.insertItems(0, entries)
        except OSError as err:
            with open(file, 'w'):
                pass

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        should_save = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, "Save data", 
                                                     "Should the data be saved?",
                                                     defaultButton = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes)
        if should_save == QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.write_to_file(self.save_file)
        return super().closeEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = MyMainWindow()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/840947/heike Heike Thank you for your response it worked Thank you a lot God bless you

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please write why you did this why you did that in code cause I am new to python and pyqt5 and I am struggling to understand what you wrote. Could you please be specific and write them in code as comments. Thanks again

Comment: @TimAlym keep in mind that the above code is probably just a quick example of how to do what you wanted done -- it is up to you to now put that in a much cleaner and more properly designed bit of code --  for instances if you are not using sys.argv to bring in command line arguments as this program does not then `app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)` should be `app = QtWidgets.QApplication([ ])`